# ¿Cómo conectar mi vs code a una instacia en Amazon?

Tags: aws, vscode, amazon

¿Cómo conectar mi 'VSCod' a una instancia en Amazon para poder revisar los archivos que están publicados y editarlos?

Comment: Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/332898/edit) para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): e incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Para este tipo de tareas ya existen "*elastic beanstalk*" y "*code deploy*". La única razón por la que necesitarías hacer eso es porque alguien se dedica a tocar manualmente esos archivos... lo cual no suele ser una práctica recomendable